# Cocoa program exits with no crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I managed to create a bug where a cocoa program is exiting.

-[NSApplication terminate:] is apparently not called.

Nor is -[NSException init].

There is no crash. What I am seeing in gdb is that exit() is being called directly from NSApplicationMain without going through the normal [NSApplication terminate] path.

Any ideas about how to debug this and/or how this (seemingly "impossible" behavior) could happen?

Thanks in advance from a cocoa newb.

Comment: What happens if you put a breakpoint at `exit`?  Who is calling `exit`?

Comment: exit() is being called directly from NSApplicationMain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mulling this over I guessed that I was doing something wrong "in the big picture".  So, "in the big picture", what I was doing is calling a modal dialog (by loading a window nib, showing the window and then using [NSApplication beginModalSessionForWindow]...[NSApp runModalSession]... and upon close [NSApp endModalSession].  This has worked for me in other chunks of code no big deal.  The critical *difference* was that this modal window was being loaded and run out of another class's awakeFromNib.

I wrote a simple app that will reproduce this behavior.  So what happens is that the modal dialog loads happily and when you close the modal window not only does it close but the app exits. I imagine that this is an "as designed" behavior.  I was reading up in [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html) to see if I could understand why this was so but I am will muddled on it.  I surmise that somehow my dialog's modal event loop has hijacked the app's event loop so that when the dialog ends so does the app.

If anybody has a better understanding of this mistake please feel free to enlighten us...

Thanks to all for reading and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I would start with judicious use of breakpoints.  Narrow it down to the last place where your code is seen before the faux crash and then start looking around that area for memory issues.  Whenever I have really strange behavior, it's almost entirely due to a strange memory bug.

Answer (score 2):

There are few remaining routes that would cause your application to voluntarily exit without going through the normal [NSApplication terminate] path.

Try setting a breakpoint on "stop:". I suspect somehow, perhaps an inappropriately named performSelector call? Or a badly named IB connection, you are calling this method, which is documented to exit from the main event loop.

Comment: Relevant documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/stop: Note that you need not send it directly to the application; you could also be sending it to the First Responder, either by hooking it up there in IB or by setting a UI element's action but not its target.

Comment: I tried a break on [NSApplication stop:] but no joy there either. After mulling this over I guessed that I was doing something wrong "in the big picture"...

Answer (score 0):

PS -- I changed my code to use [NSApplication runModalForWindow:] instead of the modal session calls and all is well (I think).  (Using the modal session would allow me to launch a web browser from a modal dialog -- while runModalForWindow does not -- but in this case I don't need that functionality.)